# Problems with APC setup and apache2 errors

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I am getting a series of errors that don't recognize; I suspect that it as something to do with APC but I am not sure:

```
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  Unknown: 1. h->opened_path=[null]  h->filename=[/var/www/sitenetos.com/index.php]\n in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  Unknown: apc_cache_find [2231284]\n in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  require(): 1. h->opened_path=[null]  h->filename=[/var/www/sitenetos.com/application/bootstrap.php]\n in /var/www/sitenetos.com/index.php on line 102
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  require(): apc_cache_find [2232922]\n in /var/www/sitenetos.com/index.php on line 102
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  require(): 1. h->opened_path=[null]  h->filename=[/var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana/core.php]\n in /var/www/sitenetos.com/application/bootstrap.php on line 6
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  require(): apc_cache_find [2231738]\n in /var/www/sitenetos.com/application/bootstrap.php on line 6
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  require(): 1. h->opened_path=[null]  h->filename=[/var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana.php]\n in /var/www/sitenetos.com/application/bootstrap.php on line 16
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  require(): apc_cache_find [2231726]\n in /var/www/sitenetos.com/application/bootstrap.php on line 16
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  require(): 1. h->opened_path=[null]  h->filename=[/var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/i18n.php]\n in /var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana/core.php on line 496
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  require(): apc_cache_find [2231723]\n in /var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana/core.php on line 496
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  require(): 1. h->opened_path=[null]  h->filename=[/var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana/i18n.php]\n in /var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana/core.php on line 496
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  require(): apc_cache_find [2231782]\n in /var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana/core.php on line 496
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  require(): 1. h->opened_path=[null]  h->filename=[/var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana/exception.php]\n in /var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana/core.php on line 496
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  require(): apc_cache_find [2231742]\n in /var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana/core.php on line 496
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  require(): 1. h->opened_path=[null]  h->filename=[/var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana/kohana/exception.php]\n in /var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana/core.php on line 496
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Notice:  require(): apc_cache_find [2231785]\n in /var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana/core.php on line 496
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Debug' not found in /var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana/kohana/exception.php on line 203
[Wed Jun 08 19:59:31 2011] [error] [client 10.211.55.2] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Debug' not found in /var/www/sitenetos.com/system/classes/kohana/kohana/exception.php on line 203
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some software doesn't play nice with APC, or vice versa.

You can always disable it for that directory to see if it's APC causing the error.

Add to `/var/www/sitenetos.com/.htaccess` :

```
php_flag apc.cache_by_default Off
php_flag apc.enabled Off
```

Then check to see if it happens again.

Comment: It works! So what do I do from here?

Comment: I am using Thrift and I need APC... Will that configuration have any negative effect?

Comment: It seems the problem originate on how I setup APC. When you install it at the start it ask if you want to debug or something you select the default. That's not what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You must give APC lot of memory. Increase shm_size option until APC have 20% of unused memory.

Use apc.php for apc package to check memory usage.